# How to force Kubernetes to update deployment with a pod in every node

Tags: deployment, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I would like to know if there is a way to force Kubernetes, during a deploy, to use every node in the cluster. 
The question is due some attempts that I have done where I noticed a situation like this:

- a cluster of 3 nodes
- I update a deployment with a command like: `kubectl set image deployment/deployment_name my_repo:v2.1.2`
- Kubernetes updates the cluster

At the end I execute `kubectl get pod` and I notice that 2 pods have been deployed in the same node. 
So after the update, the cluster has this configuration:

- one node with 2 pods
- one node with 1 pod
- one node without any pod (totally without any workload)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scheduler will try to figure out the most reasonable way of scheduling at given point in time, which can change later on and results in situations like you described. Two simple ways to manage this in one way or another are :

- use DaemonSet instead of Deployment : will make sure you have one and only one pod per node (matching nodeSelector / tolerations etc.)
- use PodAntiAffinity : you can make sure that two pods of the same deployment in the same version are never deployed on the same node. This is what I personally prefer for many apps (unless I want more then one to be scheduled per node). Note that it will be in a bit of trouble if you decide to scale your deployment to more replicas then you have nodes.
  Example for versioned PodAntiAffinity I use :

  ```
  metadata:
    labels:
      app: {{ template "fullname" . }}
      version: {{ .Values.image.tag }}
  spec:
    affinity:
      podAntiAffinity:
        requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        - labelSelector:
            matchExpressions:
            - key: app
              operator: In
              values: ["{{ template "fullname" . }}"]
            - key: version
              operator: In
              values: ["{{ .Values.image.tag }}"]
          topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
  ```
- consider fiddling with [Descheduler](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/descheduler) which is like an evil twin of Kubes Scheduler component which will cause deleting of pods for them tu reschedule differently

Comment: I'm reading the documentation (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity) and it's just what I was looking for. But is there a way to create a single yaml deployment file to ensure that every pod will be deployed in a single node? So a single file to be executed and not 2 different yaml files as in the example

Comment: I tried to use the option PodAntiAffinity and deployment is working but now I'm facing another problem. In fact when I try to update the deployment with the command: `kubectl set image deployment/apache-deployment my_repo:v2.1.2` then I get this error: `apache-deployment-7c774d67f5-l69lb  No nodes are available that match all of the predicates: MatchInterPodAffinity (3)`. Any suggestion?

Comment: It's strange because I take the code from the example described here (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity) changing only the name of the app. And the deployment is working so the yaml file should be correct. The problem appears when I try to update the deployment not before

Comment: ah, that makes sense :) if you update things might get a bit tricky. This is why I have 2 labels used for antiaffinity like `app: myapp` and `version: v1.0.1` so that antiaffinity is restricting only pods of the same version

Comment: Could you please provide me an example with a podAntiAffinity matchExpressions with 2 params? Because I'm not understanding how manage the `version: v1.0.1` (that is hardcoded) in the yaml file when you have to update to 1.0.2 for example

Comment: added to response above

Comment: I'm adding a comment just to confirm that the best solution to make sure you have only one pod per node is using the **DaemonSet**.  Unfortunately using the approach to reapply the deployment yaml does not guarantee that after deployment each node has a single pod. A situation where a node has 2 pod for example is very rare, but I have to recommend the DaemonSet to have a more reliable update strategy

Answer (score 1):

I tried some solutions and what is working at the moment is simply based <strike>on the change of version inside my deployment.yaml</strike> on **DaemonSet** controller.

I mean:

1) I have to deploy for the 1' time my application based on a pod with some containers. These pods should be deployed on every cluster node (I have 3 nodes). <strike>I have set up the deployment setting in the yaml file with the option `replicas` equal to 3:</strike>

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2 # for versions before 1.8.0 use apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
  labels:
    app: webpod  
spec:
  replicas: 3
....
```

I have set up the daemonset (or ds) in the yaml file with the option *updateStrategy* equal to *RollingUpdate*:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: my-daemonset

spec:
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
...
```

The version used for one of my containers is 2.1 for example

---

2) <strike>I execute the deployment with the command: `kubectl apply -f my-deployment.yaml`</strike>

I execute the deployment with the command: `kubectl apply -f my-daemonset.yaml`

---

3) I get one pod for every node without problem

---

4) Now I want to update the deployment changing the version of the image that I use for one of my containers.  <strike>So I simply change the yaml file editing 2.1 with 2.2. Then I re-launch the command: `kubectl apply -f my-deployment.yaml`</strike>

So I can simply change the version of the image (2.1 -> 2.2) with this command:

```
kubectl set image ds/my-daemonset my-container=my-repository:v2.2
```

---

5) <strike>Again, I obtain one pod for every node without problem</strike>

Behavior very different if instead I use the command:

```
kubectl set image deployment/my-deployment my-container=xxxx:v2.2
```

In this case I get a wrong result where a node has 2 pod, a node 1 pod and last node without any pod...

To see how the deployment evolves, I can launch the command:

```
kubectl rollout status ds/my-daemonset
```

getting something like that

```
Waiting for rollout to finish: 0 out of 3 new pods have been updated...
Waiting for rollout to finish: 0 out of 3 new pods have been updated...
Waiting for rollout to finish: 1 out of 3 new pods have been updated...
Waiting for rollout to finish: 1 out of 3 new pods have been updated...
Waiting for rollout to finish: 1 out of 3 new pods have been updated...
Waiting for rollout to finish: 2 out of 3 new pods have been updated...
Waiting for rollout to finish: 2 out of 3 new pods have been updated...
Waiting for rollout to finish: 2 out of 3 new pods have been updated...
Waiting for rollout to finish: 2 of 3 updated pods are available...
daemon set "my-daemonset" successfully rolled out
```